Deleting a BIM360/ACC File?
I'm trying something that seems straightforward - to delete an item within a BIM360/ACC project (which I know is actually to Post a new version that is deleted).
I've followed closely the instructions here:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/delete-and-restore-file/
My REST call is almost identical.
However, I'm receiving this error:
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"errors":[{"id":"c235208c-c820-427c-beb1-f3c2858efb7b","status":"400","code":"BAD_INPUT","title":"One or more input values in the request were bad","detail":"Schema "versions:autodesk.core:Deleted -1.0" was not found."}]}
Any guidance that someone could offer?

May I see the request payload you sent?
Looks like you have set: data.attributes.extension.type:"versions:autodesk.core:Deleted -1.0" instead of versions:autodesk.core:Deleted
I have tested on my end and this request seems to work okay:


{
        "jsonapi": {
          "version": "1.0"
        },
        "data": {
          "type": "versions",
          "attributes": {
            "extension": {
               "type":"versions:autodesk.core:Deleted",
              "version": "1.0"
            }
          },
          "relationships": {
            "item": {
              "data": {
                "type": "items",
                "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:0p70Kns_QsGgm6oSOs-_Xg"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }



